# How to speed up of simple algorithm that takes inputs from user

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, printing

I am wondering how can I speed up the following code. It takes the inputs from user and print the most repeated item. The first input is the number of values that user wants to enter.

```
N = int(input())
B=[]
for i in range(N):
    b = (int(input()))
    B.append( (b) )
print(max(set(B), key=B.count))
```

Comment: I can't imagine a person typing in enough numbers to make this slow.  How long is this taking to run?

Comment: The numbers could be entered by robot and it may be thousands. I need it less than 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```py
from collections import Counter

Counter(B).most_common(n=1)[0][0]
```

With a time comparison:

```py
from random import randint

B = [randint(0, 25) for _ in range(10000)]

%%timeit
max(set(B), key=B.count)
# 3.89 ms ± 63.4 µs per loop

%%timeit
Counter(B).most_common(n=1)[0][0]
# 434 µs ± 53.8 µs per loop
```

[image: Set vs Counter runtime]